# Definition of Orlicz-Sobolev space $W^{1,A}_0(\Omega)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, orlicz-spaces

i have this definition 
[image]

with this definition can i say that $u\in W^{1,A}_0(\Omega)$ impies that $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ ?

Comment: In what sense are you interpreting $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega $?

Comment: @Jose27 i don't understand

Comment: Well, potentially the boundary of $\Omega $ has dimension less than $n $ meaning it has Lebesgue measure 0. On the other hand Sobolev functions are in principle only defined a.e., so some care must be taken in defining a restriction to the boundary.

Comment: @Jose27 so we can say that $u=0 $ on $\partial \Omega$ , like in $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$

Comment: I don't actually know what $W^{m,A}$ means. But I can say this: there is only a well-defined trace operator on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ when the boundary of $\Omega$ is sufficiently regular. Thus even in ordinary Sobolev spaces, the statement "$u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \Rightarrow u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$" need not make sense, depending on the character of $\Omega$. If you assume Lipschitz boundary then everything is OK, of course.